# How to pass URL of folder to codebase in applet?

Tags: java, applet, classpath

I have apple.html in `C:/Java1` and apple1.class in `C:/Java`, I have given path of class file in applet `codebase` but cannot initialize the applet.

Here is code

apple.html in C:/Java1

```
<applet code="apple.class" codebase="file:/C:/Java/" alt="Applet not printed value" width="200" height="200">
</applet>
```

apple1.class in c:/Java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.*; 
import java.lang.*;

public class apple1 extends Applet  
{
       public void paint(Graphics g) 
       {
           g.drawString("hi...I am", 50, 50); 
       } 
}
```

when I run code using

```
appletviewer applet.html
```

It gives applet not initialized.

Comment: How are you loading the webpage? Are you loading it from a web server or from your local file system?

Comment: My untested guess is that you should use `"../Java"`.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: @Code-Guru  I reckon your guess should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codebase is wrong use like

```
codebase="file:///C:/Java/"
```

EDIT:

The class name allso need to change

```
code="apple.class"
```

but the class name in java file is `apple1`.

also the code in the `paint` method doesn't call `super.paint()`, and don't ask why nothing appears in the browser. But you didn't use the browser yet, so it may be in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ... I have written .class name apple.class instead of apple1.class

Answer (score 0):

Try `codebase="../Java"`. This will give a path relative to the location of the HTML page.